# How to move to a specific window on Ubuntu using Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu

OS: Ubuntu

Is there a way to move focus to a different window. For example, "Stack Overflow" is current focus and another window say Pycharms has a script running, I would like Pycharms to come in focus when script is finished running.

I have looked around and cant seem to find a solution. Pyautogui will allow me to do Alt+Tab but that is not really a good solution when multiple windows are open.

Comment: The `xdotool` utility might be of use. https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/find-window-by-its-name-and-activate-it-bring-to-foreground/

Comment: @AKX I am trying it out, but the output is always 0, trying to figure out how to retain the window number into a variable.

Comment: Tried `subprocess.check_output()`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `xdotool` and `xargs`, maybe

```
os.system('xdotool search --name "PyCharm" | xargs xdotool windowactivate')
```

would do the trick, since `xdotool search` outputs the window ID, and `xargs` lets you paste it into another command's command line, as it were.

Comment: With the above, I get `XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)
xdotool: Unknown command: 50331664
Run 'xdotool help' if you want a command list` I will try the subprocess_check_output.

Comment: Please post the subprocess.check_output answer. It works with a combination of extracting only digits from output.